# Extending circleMarker "icon" formatting

Tags: leaflet

I found some genius code. But I do not understand how they designed the marker pin

Is the MarkerPin made from svg in some way or did they just come up with the design out of maths?
I have [this svg icon](https://register.geonorge.no/symbol/files/tilgjengelighet/sittegruppe_positiv_groenn.svg) I would like to use. So how would i go about translating that to the code below? I may be stupid and they are completely unrelated to svg.

```
L.MarkerPin = L.CircleMarker.extend({
    _updatePath: function () {
        this._renderer._updateMarkerPin(this);
    },
    _containsPoint: function (p) {
        var r = this._radius;

        var insideCircle =
                p.add([0, r * 2]).distanceTo(this._point) <= r + this._clickTolerance();

        var a = this._point,
                b = a.subtract([0.58 * r, r]),
                c = a.subtract([-0.58 * r, r]);

        var insideTriangle = true;

        var ap_x = p.x - a.x;
        var ap_y = p.y - a.y;
        var p_ab = (b.x - a.x) * ap_y - (b.y - a.y) * ap_x > 0;
        var p_ac = (c.x - a.x) * ap_y - (c.y - a.y) * ap_x > 0;
        var p_bc = (c.x - b.x) * (p.y - b.y) - (c.y - b.y) * (p.x - b.x) > 0;

        if (p_ac === p_ab) insideTriangle = false;
        if (p_bc !== p_ab) insideTriangle = false;
        return insideTriangle || insideCircle;
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle with complete example:

https://jsfiddle.net/n2jf5c4q/

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is only to check if a point (f.e. a click position) is in the area of the Pin. I think this is made because the creator don't wanted that the click event is fired when it is clicked on the area of a circle.

What you mean is this code:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
ctx.lineTo(p.x - 0.58 * r, p.y - r);
ctx.arc(p.x, p.y - 2 * r, r, -Math.PI * 1.161, Math.PI * 0.161);
ctx.closePath();
```

This is normal canvas drawing and has nothing to do with svg

**Update**

I tried a little bit around and i found a way, but this is not supported for all browsers.

You can use `Path2D` render the svg as canvas path (maybe you have to resize the svg)

```
window.p = new Path2D("M0-0.1h20.8v20.9H0V-0.1z M0.5,0.4v19.9h19.8V0.4H0.5z M19,14h-3.2l1.6,3.4h-1.7L14,14H6.7l-1.6,3.4H3.3L4.9,14H1.8v-1.6 h3.9l0.8-1.6H4.1V9.1h12.5v1.6h-2.4l0.8,1.6h4V14z M7.4,12.4h5.8l-0.7-1.6H8.2L8.1,11l-0.3,0.6L7.4,12.4z");

L.Canvas.include({
  _updateCircle: function (layer) {

    if (!this._drawing || layer._empty()) { return; }

    var p = layer._point,
      ctx = this._ctx,
      r = Math.max(Math.round(layer._radius), 1),
      s = (Math.max(Math.round(layer._radiusY), 1) || r) / r;

    if (s !== 1) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.scale(1, s);
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y / s, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);

    if (s !== 1) {
      ctx.restore();
    }

    var x = p.x-10; // -10 because of ~20 is the img size
    var y = p.y-10;

    ctx.translate(x,y);
    ctx.fill(window.p);

    //this._fillStroke(ctx, layer);
  },
});


var canvasRenderer = L.canvas();
new L.CircleMarker([51.505, -0.09], {
  renderer: canvasRenderer
}).bindPopup('hello').addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: okay i understand now, so frustating that I cant use normal icons with canvas. Thankyou Falke

Comment: @HenrikMaaland have you looked into https://github.com/totomaze/Leaflet.Canvas-Markers ?

Comment: Yes, but that one was broken so i also tried this one https://github.com/IITC-CE/Leaflet.Canvas-Markers but could not get it to work in my own project because of rdash

Comment: @HenrikMaaland I updated my answer, maybe it helps you